# Mysql error on datetime variable

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am not a natural programmer, I can usually fumble my way through using this site, but this query error has me stumped.  The query is in a form that is exporting the data to a CSV file.  The 'fromdate' and 'todate' are pulled from the datepicker jquery widgit modified as dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"+ " " + "00:00:00" & dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"+ " " + "23:59:59"

I'm joining 1 derived table with 2 other tables. The query runs fine in mysql when I substitute the variables for values, but seems to be complaining about the datetime and I've tried formatting it multiple ways to no avail. I have tried the query with and without using strtotime.

.

```
if ( isset($_POST["GetList"]) )
{
$ids = implode(',',$_POST['svvendors']);
$startdate = ($_POST['fromdate']);
$donedate= ($_POST['todate']);
$fromdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$startdate"));
$todate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$donedate"));

$sql1 = 'select t1.npanxx, t1.state, t2.bnumber, t2.asr, t2.total, t2.carid, t2.carjur, t2.date, t3.vendorid FROM sncodes as t1 INNER JOIN (select bnumber, (select sum(carduration>0) / sum(carduration)*100) as ASR, (select count(carduration)) as total, carid, carjur, date FROM svcdrs group by bnumber,carid,carjur) as t2 on t1.npanxx = t2.bnumber AND calldate >=('.$fromdate.') AND calldate <= ('.$todate.') INNER JOIN (select vendorid from svvendors) as t3 ON t2.carid = t3.vendorid AND vendorid=('.$ids.') order by npanxx';
```

check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00) AND calldate <= (2018-01-02 23:59:59) INNER JOIN (select vendorid from' at line 1

Comment: try `$sql1 = 'select t1.npanxx, t1.state, t2.bnum . . . .() AND calldate >=(STR_TO_DATE('.$fromdate.') ) ...calldate <= (STR_TO_DATE('.$todate.')) .......`

Comment: try removing parens and add quotes like  `... AND calldate >="'.$fromdate.'"...`

Comment: Are these DATE or DATETIME columns? If they are DATE columns this won't work as the time part is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use either

```
 $sql1 = "select t1.npanxx, t1.state, t2.bnumber, t2.asr, t2.total, t2.carid, t2.carjur, t2.date, t3.vendorid FROM sncodes as t1 INNER JOIN (select bnumber, (select sum(carduration>0) / sum(carduration)*100) as ASR, (select count(carduration)) as total, carid, carjur, date FROM svcdrs group by bnumber,carid,carjur) as t2 on t1.npanxx = t2.bnumber AND calldate >=STR_TO_DATE('$fromdate','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND calldate <= STR_TO_DATE('$todate','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') INNER JOIN (select vendorid from svvendors) as t3 ON t2.carid = t3.vendorid AND vendorid=('$ids') order by npanxx";
```

or

```
 $sql1 = "select t1.npanxx, t1.state, t2.bnumber, t2.asr, t2.total, t2.carid, t2.carjur, t2.date, t3.vendorid FROM sncodes as t1 INNER JOIN (select bnumber, (select sum(carduration>0) / sum(carduration)*100) as ASR, (select count(carduration)) as total, carid, carjur, date FROM svcdrs group by bnumber,carid,carjur) as t2 on t1.npanxx = t2.bnumber AND calldate >='$fromdate' AND calldate <= '$todate' INNER JOIN (select vendorid from svvendors) as t3 ON t2.carid = t3.vendorid AND vendorid=('$ids') order by npanxx";
```

Comment: STR_TO_DATE works when I removed the strtotime lines and called the variables directly from the $_POST.  Otherwise it defaults to 1970-01-01.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In MariaDB 'DATE' field format doesn't have hh:mm:ss part. So Date is just a date 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Most probably 'calldate' is of this type. So in comparisons you may not use 'hh:mm:ss', you should undo widget modifications to return date in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format, then rewrite your code so, that sql date range comparison looked like calldate>='$fromdate' and calldate&ltdate_add('$todate', interval 1 day). Next *very* important notice - never use form values in sql queries without escaping or prepared statements. Otherwise your code is vulnerable to SQL injections and in theory someone can pass '; drop database customers; --' in $fromdate field date and then all your data is gone.